# How to set the DPI in a Hi-Res screen? The default setting is too small

Tags: resolution, display-settings, dpi

I'm running Linux Mint MATE 17.3 on a brand new Asus UX305FA with screen resolution 1920x1080.

Everything is super small. I would like that the overall appearance is managed correctly like in the other os. I'm not able to find anything to solve this problem.

The only think that I was able to find is [this post](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=195327) but it is a bit outdated and not sure if it will work on my laptop. I saw that in Ubuntu this is somehow managed, but cannot find any settings in Mint. I think there must be a way to set the resolution on this kind of screen as they are not really new. I used a 1280x800 screen for 7 years, that's why I'm not updated with hi-resolution device.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

I may recommend you to follow [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/HiDPI) and [this](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2911509/how-to-make-linuxs-desktop-look-good-on-high-resolution-displays.html) guides to set up HiDPi on Linux properly.

Comment: I've done the same following the guide in my link, and it set the parameters properly (in my case I see the right dimension of the screen and the 166x166 dots per inch resolution), but actually there is no difference in how the display shows the thing.